# how to convert response of soap webservice to an object in visual studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I am new in webservices so I need to know what is the best way to convert my response that I am getting from my soap webservice to an object created in my project. Below is my code that is working fine and returning XML data in variable backstr. Any hint? Thanks in advance.

```
    Public Function function1(ByVal claimNum As String) As String
            Try
                Dim URLReq As HttpWebRequest
                Dim URLRes As HttpWebResponse

                Dim strURL As String = "http://mywebservice?strVisaID=" & claimNum

                If Trim(strURL) <> "" Then

                    URLReq = WebRequest.Create(strURL)
                    URLRes = URLReq.GetResponse

                    Dim res As HttpWebResponse = URLReq.GetResponse()
                    Dim sr As New StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.[Default])

                    Dim backstr As String = sr.ReadToEnd()


                    If URLRes.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                        Return backstr + " ok done "
                    Else
                        Return backstr + " something is wrong "
                    End If

                Else
                    Return "empty url"
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                Return " exception" + ex.Message
            End Try
 End Function
```

Comment: I've never used SOAP, but I've recently worked on a project where I used the JSON Serializer to serialize data transfer objects into JSON and vise versa for communicating with a REST service. _System.XML.Serialization_ appears to offer similar functionality for XML.  Make sure to decorate your object with the <Serializable> tag.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316730

Comment: Yes this one is working, but I don't want to work with files ( saving response in product.xml then reading it and deserialize it). I need to deserialize it directly.Any hint ?

Comment: Check the doc, you can pass a [stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875(v=vs.110).aspx). It doesn't have to be a file.